# Zabbix - users cannot see graphs

Tags: zabbix

i configured new dashboard with wanted hosts and graphs and everything is ok with that, but other users cannot see graps,just timelines.
Can somebody give me advice related to this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make your dashboard Public. It's not referring to non authenticated public but the other users that didn't create the dashboard